# Empty/blank print page

Tags: javascript, magento, printing

I'm trying to print product page using this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.print();"><span>Print</span></a>
```

but I get empty page. Also, trying to print via Ctrl+P from my browser.
Any ideas how I can fix this or just even start to debug print action?

I'm using magento 1.8

Comment: fiexed. Problem was in my print.css file. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This should get you working

```
<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.print();"><span>Print</span></a>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see the difference with my code. Anyway I call `javascript:window.print();` and it returns me empty page